# How to embed large arrays in Google Cloud Datastore without reaching the 1MB size limit?

Tags: google-app-engine, nosql, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

My project mainly utilizes two different tools from Google:

1. **Natural Language API** to analyze and save *entities* and *syntax* of hundreds of docs
2. **Datastore** to store each document along with its data retrieved from the Google NL API

I absolutely must save the tokens and entities otherwise I would have to call the Google NL API each and every time I work with a given document.

However, when a document is over a thousand words (i.e. extremely often) I cannot save my document inside Google Datastore.

I receive a `400` error saying `entity is too big`. It's around 2 to 5MB depending on the topic.

I also have `The value of property 'tokens' is longer than 1048487 bytes` when I try to Blob it.

I tried serializing the array and turning it into a Blob but same result.

**Any way I could make this work without migrating to MongoDB?**

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest you 3 options:

1. **Use compression**. (*tactical*) Usually text data are very well compressed. So you may begin to fit into 1MB limit
2. **Use sharding**. Split the data in multiple entities and store/read them together. Join on read as needed.
3. **Migrate to blob storage**. For example https://cloud.google.com/storage/

There are other options/solutions but this 3 are probably easiest to implement.

Comment: Compression is already what I have done, it may work at times but as soon as a document has a (much) higher wordcount, it fails again.

Sharding would be too complicated I think and some of these arrays of tokens or entities are themselves over 1MiB.

Blob storage is possible but it's quite a bit of gymnastic and network calls just to retrieve the full document (datastore's document with title, meta, etc; and then calls to Google Cloud Storage for the two lists of tokens and entities.)

Comment: I don't see how shards are difficult. Basically just 2 wrapping function - 1 for write, 1 for read. Maybe 30-50 lines of code?